# No Return Statement Prroblem

Tags: java, return

I´ve written this function, and Eclipse says there is **no return statement** of type `Date` but there is one in else{}!

Where could be the problem?

```
public Date compareDate(Date Kred_Deb_Date, Date Book_Date){
    Date date1 = null;
    if (Book_Date.compareTo(Kred_Deb_Date)<0){
        date1 = get_book_date();
        compareDate(Kred_Deb_Date, date1);
    }else if (Book_Date.compareTo(Kred_Deb_Date)>0){
        date1 = Book_Date;
        return date1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Return should comes after your condition or you can send default date object. if no condition satisfy then it will return default date.

please check below code, I have changed return code position.

```
public Date compareDate(Date Kred_Deb_Date, Date Book_Date){
    Date date1 = null;
    if (Book_Date.compareTo(Kred_Deb_Date)<0){
        date1 = get_book_date();
        compareDate(Kred_Deb_Date, date1);
    }else if (Book_Date.compareTo(Kred_Deb_Date)>0){
        date1 = Book_Date;

    }
        return date1;
}
```

Comment: And having a *single* `return` value can help debugging since you can set a breakpoints more easily. Have an upvote!

Comment: :) you can accept my answer if it works for you. thanks.

Comment: This is the common solution for this. In my Opinion, if you use Java 8, it's more asthetic to use `Optional` instead of the possibility to return a `null`. Also the second line in your first `if` is returning a value which isn't used.

Answer (score 1):

Java insists that for a non-`void` function, there is a `return` value on all program control paths.

The way you currently have things arranged, that is not the case:

A value is not returned for `Book_Date.compareTo(Kred_Deb_Date)>0` or `Book_Date.compareTo(Kred_Deb_Date) == 0`.

Did you mean to write `return compareDate(Kred_Deb_Date, date1);` in the `true` part of the `if` block, and replace the `else if (...)` with `else`?

Answer (score 1):

If your `if` condition is verified, you won't return anything.

Two solutions:

- Add a return statement in your **if**
- Add a return statement at the **end of your function**

In this case, I guess your trying to do the following:

```
public Date compareDate(Date Kred_Deb_Date, Date Book_Date) {
    Date date1 = null;
    if (Book_Date.compareTo(Kred_Deb_Date) < 0) {
        date1 = get_book_date();
        compareDate(Kred_Deb_Date, date1);
    } else if (Book_Date.compareTo(Kred_Deb_Date) > 0) {
        date1 = Book_Date;
    }
    return date1;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The common answer by moving your return statement one line down is already given, so here is a more modern solution which prevents you from getting a `null` as a return value:

```
public Optional<Date> compareDate(Date Kred_Deb_Date, Date Book_Date){
    Date date1 = null;
    if (Book_Date.compareTo(Kred_Deb_Date)<0){
        date1 = get_book_date();
        compareDate(Kred_Deb_Date, date1);
    } else if (Book_Date.compareTo(Kred_Deb_Date)>0){
        date1 = Book_Date;
    }
    return Optional.ofNullable(date1);
}
```

but despite this, there is an unused recursive call which return value isnt used (first if, second line), just for notice.